# Extend column background into grid gutters

Tags: css, frontend, css-grid

Consider this…

You are creating three column layout using grid system. Your container is fixed sized and centered using margin:0 auto.

Your design specs calls for first column to have background color that extends to the left edge of browser.

Any idea how you can achieve this? [I could make it work this way](https://codepen.io/pratikgmehta/pen/yjrgRx), which is kind of a hack and it may not work for certain kind of image backgrounds.

**HTML:**

```
<main>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <header>
        <h1>Hey There!</h1>
      </header>
      <div>
        <h2>Column 2</h2>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Column 3<h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

**CSS**

```
main {
  min-width: 800px;
}

section {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #dfdfdf 50%, #fff 50%);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin:0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

section > * {
  min-height: 200px;
}

.container > div {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also generate the background using a pseudoelement.

The `left` value is large enough to keep the background extending out of the screen. It may be problematic if you need precise position of a background image.

Also, you could consider `grid-gap` instead of adding `padding-left` to the grid items.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  min-width: 800px;
}

section {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

section>* {
  min-height: 200px;
}

.container>div {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

header {
  position: relative;
}

header:before {
  content: '';
  background: lightgrey;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50vw;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <header>
        <h1>Hey There!</h1>
      </header>
      <div>
        <h2>Column 2</h2>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Column 3</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: faster this time :p

Comment: Thanks sol & @Temani Afif! Mathematically, both of our solution has a fundamental assumption flaw - what if 50% (50vw) is not enough - what if gutter area space is larger than 50% on bigger screens? I know today such devices are hard to find. BUT, I will take your solution and mark it as possible answer. :)

Comment: @PratikMehta you simply increase it :) make it 100vw and you will be sure it's enough ;)

Comment: That’s true. Then it becomes full-proof solution. Good conversation!!

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the columns stretch the full width of the container, and then aligning the content inside to appear as three centered columns.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  min-height: 50px;
}

header {
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

section {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

p { text-align: center;}
p > span { padding: 5px; background-color: aqua; }
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <header>
        <h1>Hey There!</h1>
      </header>
      <div>
        <h2>Column 2</h2>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Column 3</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
<p><span>True Center</span></p>
```

### [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MGMWOE)